# Can I set some default pages to be created on every creation of a new blog

Tags: multisite

The pages like "about" will be created automatically when a new blog is created. Likewise I need some other pages which should appear automatically when a blog is created under my multisites.

How can I configure the default pages to be created with a new blog under a multisite?

For ex.: If I have a multisite on `example.com`. Every blog created under this site should have 
Home, About, My store, My address.

Comment: I actually plan on creating a plugin for this. I am planning to define an easily created format for saving and restoring a post to and from a text file and to even create a post in this format by hand by a non-technical person. But I haven't started work on it yet so I can only tell you about what I envision it will be. In the mean time, *@kevtrout* has a reasonable solution below.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: I suppose it would be nice to A) Create template versions of each default page as a standard page, and B) Define those pages as 'default' using a form in the admin section.  When an 'MU-style' blog is activated, the template pages are copied to that blog account.  Seems like a great idea for the Multi-site uses of WP.  My needs in the past have required default content to appear in the write-post textarea.  Never did figure it out...new question perhaps?

Comment: *@kevtrout* - write-post textarea?  You mean post_content?  If not then yeah, a new question. That's what SE is here for. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend creating a function in your functions.php file that ties to the action hook `activate_blog`.  Use the WordPress functions [get_pages()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) to see if your default pages exist.  If they do not, create them with [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

```
add_action('activate_blog','my_default_pages');

function my_default_pages(){
    $default_pages = array('About','Home','My Store','My Address');
    $existing_pages = get_pages();

    foreach($existing_pages as $page){
        $temp[] = $page->post_title;
        }


    $pages_to_create = array_diff($default_pages,$temp);

    foreach($pages_to_create as $new_page_title){

            // Create post object
            $my_post = array();
            $my_post['post_title'] = $new_page_title;
            $my_post['post_content'] = 'This is my '.$new_page_title.' page.';
            $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
            $my_post['post_type'] = 'page';



            // Insert the post into the database
            $result = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

        }
        }
```

To test this function on your own site, try setting the hook to `wp_head`.  It will run on each page load and insert the pages that don't exist, with the content in $my_post['post_content'].  *Does the 'activate_blog' hook run when blogs are created in a multi-site context?  I don't know.*

Refer to the codex page for wp_insert_post that I linked to for the complete list of default parameters available.

Comment: I have grabbed the code you have given and pasted in my theme's functions.php with out any changes. And later I have created a new site to check whether it is created with newly added pages. But unfortunately I have not find any changes in new site or in main site.

I think I committed mistake some where .

Comment: Follow my recommendation to set the hook to wp_head above to test whether the code is working for you.  Then look into exactly when the 'activate_blog' hook fires.

Comment: Sorry ! I am still unable to follow where to use wp_head and how to proceed .I am newer to wordpress.I know a little bit of php and not much familiar to coding .

Comment: Change `add_action('activate_blog','my_default_pages');`, to  `add_action('wp_head','my_default_pages');`.  Then go read about action and filter hooks: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference.  In the end, you'll need to find the hook that runs when a new blog is activated, so that pages will be created at that time. I believe that hook is `activate_blog` but the documentation for it in the codex is sparse.  Try googling for more info.  I suggest using wp_head just to test the function above.  When you know it works and have found the right hook to use, use that instead.

Comment: It worked for me when I added 'wp_head' instead of 'activate_blog'  .
This is what I did :
I have tried adding 
add_action('wp_head','my_default_pages');

Then I have created a new sub-site. The pages 'About','Home','My Store','My Address' were automatically created .

Comment: Wp_head runs on every page load. If you delete the pages that were created, then refresh the page, they will still be there because they were re-created. You should look for the hook that runs when a new blog is created to finalize the function. I thought that hook was 'activate_blog'

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again .I have tried add_action('activate_blog','my_default_pages');                                But no change using it.

Answer (score 2):

use "wpmu_activate_blog" instead of "activate_blog". it worked for me. 
thanks